# how to get 2 <p> from the article with it's HTML tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one div which have an article. and on first 2 `<p>` with it's all HTML tag.

for that, I have used the below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
    var count = 2;
    var selected = $(this).attr("data-value");   
    if (count.length === 0) 
    {   
        $("span").css({ "display": "block"});
    }else{
        $('.button').removeClass("active");
        if (selected == 'paragraphs') 
        {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var text = "";
            $( "p" ).each(function( index ) {
                if (index < count) 
                {
                    text += '<p>'+($( this ).text()).trim() + "</p><br>";
                }              
            });
            $( "#demo" ).empty();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        }
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
            <span data-value="paragraphs" class="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Paragraphs</span>
            </button>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="ltr" style="max-height: none; display: none;">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Senectus et netus et malesuada. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin.  
    </p>
    <p>
        Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. 
    </p>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

with this, I got results only text of `<p>` but I want results like.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>


<p>Senectus et netus et malesuada. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin.</p>
```

with it's all html tag.

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render a `<` character then put `&lt;` in the HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
    var count = 2;
    var selected = $(this).attr("data-value");   
    if (count.length === 0) 
    {   
        $("span").css({ "display": "block"});
    }else{
        $('.button').removeClass("active");
        if (selected == 'paragraphs') 
        {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var text = "";
            $( "p" ).each(function( index ) {
                if (index < count) 
                {
                    text += '<p>'+($( this ).text()).trim() + "</p><br>";
                }              
            });
            $( "#demo" ).empty();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
        }
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
            <span data-value="paragraphs" class="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Paragraphs</span>
            </button>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="ltr" style="max-height: none; display: none;">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Senectus et netus et malesuada. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin.  
    </p>
    <p>
        Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. 
    </p>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```